# How is the question about a whether a particular weight strategy makes sense off topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

This [question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/473640/hows-this-true-pay-attention-to-the-ounces-and-the-pounds-take-care-of-thems) was migrated to English Language and Usage (ELU) despite,

- Being **specifically about backpacking** (there are other variations of the saying that have the subject of money or writing that would be off topic)
- **Two answers** that explained how the saying specifically related to backpacking **and whether it actually made sense were one to try and follow the saying of when one selected gear for backpacking.**

Now if it had been about what the saying meant that would have been off topic and required to a different set of answers, something more like

```
The saying means that by taking care of the details,
the larger problems take care of themselves.
```

However, that is not how the people who answered the question read it nor how they answered.

### The OP clarified

> Greek, can you make it more clear whether this is about some linguistic characteristic of the sentence or if it is about the truth of that statement (however expressed) with respect to backpacking specifically?
>
> The latter: 'the truth of that statement (however expressed) with respect to backpacking specifically'.

[Source](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/473640/hows-this-true-pay-attention-to-the-ounces-and-the-pounds-take-care-of-thems/473641#comment1143844_473640)

Answer (score 2):

There was a good deal of puzzlement on ELU as to why the question was migrated, as these comments show.

> 1  Have you checked the sentence for its literal as well as idiomatic
>   meaning? It works both ways. Think again -- it's not about the English
>   language at all. – Kris 13 hours ago  Rep = 32K
>
> 5  This was an irrational migration. The question was about how this
>   sentence could be true for backpacking. The question had its origin in
>   puzzlement about an English sentence, but so what? The OP clearly
>   asked about backpacking, and we on The Great Outdoors answered the
>   question the OP asked. – ab2 11 hours ago  Rep = 22K
>
> 2  Greek, can you make it more clear whether this is about some
>   linguistic characteristic o the sentence or if it is about the truth
>   of that statement (however expressed) with respect to backpacking
>   specifically? – Mitch 7 hours ago  Rep = 49K
>
> 3  @Mitch The latter: 'the truth of that statement (however expressed)
>   with respect to backpacking specifically'. – Greek - Area 51 Proposal
>   1 hour ago
>
> 2  @Greek-Area51Proposal I have asked for it to be migrated back
>   outdoors.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1338/… – Charlie Brumbaugh 1
>   hour ago
>
> 2  I'm voting to close this question as off-topic (and to migrate
>   back) because it should never have been migrated away from
>   outdoors.stackexchange.com. This is not a question about phrasing but
>   about utility specifically for backpacking  Mitch  Rep = 49K

Now suppose the question had been:

> What does the term ***take the high ground*** mean when setting up camp at
>   Everest Base Camp?

Is this not inarguably a TGO Question (although not one of its best)?

**PS** I have no personal stake in this.  I either get rep on ELU or rep on TGO

Comment: In which case I'd have to suggest the question is just terrible for both sites. The flags made sense in that as worded it is just not about the outdoors as per our scope.

Comment: @RoryAlsop Then maybe it should have been closed as unclear (doesn't make sense given that multiple users were able to answer it) which would at least let users fix the title instead of single handly migrating a question with no chance to fix it

Comment: Not single handedly. I read the flags, agreed, and migrated as per usual.